# ADB no funciona y paraliza el sistema

Tags: android, android-studio, ubuntu, adb

Cada vez que intento ejecutar mi app Android desde Android Studio, el sistema se detiene y me veo obligado a forzar el reinicio (botonazo). Uso Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS, amd 64, android studio 3.3.2, adb 1.0.40 y la versión de platform-tools es 28.0.2.

He probado a usar una versión inferior de las platform-tools (28.0.1, 28.0.0 e incluso 27) sin éxito. Intuyo que puede deberse a alguna actualización del IDE, o herramienta relacionada, pero no doy con ello. ¿Alguna sugerencia? Gracias.

Comment: Revisa el log de errores a ver qué dice

Comment: como lo describres parece ser que el problma es una computadora lenta, ahora, puedes intentar descargar android studio nuevamente

Comment: @GilbertoIbarra Gracias pero ya he probado hasta formatée el equipo.

Comment: @A.Cedano no sé cómo puedo revisar el log exactamente. Cualquier ayuda, es bienvenida

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tras cambiar el modo de inicio en la BIOS de Legacy a UEFI y reinstalar el Sistema operativo (Debian 9), han desaparecido los fallos. ¡Aleluya! Gracias por vuestros aportes.